# VS 2022 Python - How to get going with FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi, visual-studio-2022, uvicorn

I am using Visual Studio 2022 on Win11, and trying to get to grips with Python.  In particular, I am trying out FastAPI.

I have installed FastAPI and Uvicorn.  I have a virtual environment set up for Python 3.9.

How do I get VS to run the Uvicorn server when testing?  I am trying to follow the start up guide (https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/first-steps/).  I have created a main.py file, with the required code.  When I try to run it from an interactive console, I type `uvicorn -m main:app --reload`.

The console comes back with

```
File "stdin", line 1
    uvicorn -m main:app --reload
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have tried moving the example code to another file and trying to get uvicorn to run that file, but no joy.  I think either uvicorn is not running, or the environment cannot find either uvicorn or the target main.py file.

I have tried running a DOS prompt, executing the python.exe in the venv folder, and trying to point to uvicorn directly...

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\python" -m "C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Repos\PythonApplicationFastAPITest1\env\Scripts\uvicorn" main:app --reload
```

...and I get "No module named ...uvicorn".

Comment: `uvicorn -m main:app --reload` it seems you typed this inside a Python interpreter, not in the Windows command prompt.

Comment: @mkrieger1 - Yes, Is that wrong?  I thought the Python interpreter was effectively python waiting for a command.  I have tried going to a DOS prompt and executing the python.exe with an explicit path to the uvicorn.exe in scripts, but I get "No module named path\uvicorn".

Comment: Yes, that was wrong, that command is not a Python command. What happens if you type `uvicorn -m main:app --reload` in the DOS prompt?

Comment: @mkrieger1 In DOS, I had to start uvicorn.exe with a path, when I was in the project folder containing main.py .  I had to drop the -m option, as that came back with "Error No Such Option".  I got it working by being in the project folder and typing ".\env\Scripts\uvicorn main:app --reload" .  I should now be unblocked to get going on the tutorial, thanks!  Hello, world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working with MKrieger1's engagement.

Uvicorn is a self contained app, uvicorn.exe, a server.  I was trying to start it in a Python interpreter session, which was failing.

I got it working by running uvicorn in an external DOS prompt.  I referenced the uvicorn.exe that had been installed with the FastAPI package.  The -m switch did not seem to work.

When in DOS, I changed directory to the project folder holding my main.py file.  I then issued the command...

```
.\env\scripts\uvicorn main:app --reload
```

...and this started uvicorn.exe, found main.py, app object, and ran it.  I was then able to browse to 127.0.0.1:8000 and get my "Hello, world" achievement.

```
INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2022\\Repos\\PythonApplicationFastAPITest1']
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [23000] using WatchFiles
INFO:     Started server process [20528]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     127.0.0.1:49891 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
```

Answer (score 1):

Python cannot find the uvicorn module when trying to run your FastAPI application. Ensure that the uvicorn package is installed in your virtual environment. You can install it using command:
`pip install uvicorn`

Comment: other possibilities - virtual environment is not activated, or vscode is looking at primary Python.exe instead of the venv .exe

Comment: @Sant Chanana It is apparently installed with "pip install fastapi[all]".  I can see a uvicorn folder in ".\env\lib\site-packages" and a uvicorn.exe in ".\env\scripts"

Comment: @nigh_anxiety How can I tell if the virtual environment is activated?  I started an interactive prompt from the environment, but maybe I have misunderstood.